# How to test Magento upgrade

Tags: upgrade, upgrade-script

we would like to upgrade our Magento 1.7.0.2 installation to 1.8 with around 40000 products and 25 store views.

In the past, we had bad experience upgrading our system. Our first installation was Magento version 0.8.

So we would like to test the upgrade risks before.

What is the best way for upgrading?

- Making a new Magento 1.8 installation, and then connect them to the old 1.7 database?
- Or set up a developer system and start upgrade process? How to set up a developer system for 25 store views?

Setting up and testing the new system might take a while.
During this time, we might get orders in the old Magento installation.
How can we get this orders sync with the new system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to do an upgrade is the following:

Get a database dump of your current website and test the upgrade process with a clean version of Magento. This is a version of Magento fresh out of the box. From this you can get a baseline of how your upgrade will go.

You can then access your modules by testing one at a time into your system. Finally you can move your Theme in and test this.

You can see the details on the Magento website here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

Finally, you need to do an final upgrade by putting your site into maintenance mode and running the test process.

You don't want to try to transfer orders or any other information. The upgrade process will take care of everything.

Comment: ok, when is the best time o install the modules to the fresh system? Before or after adding the old database data to the fresh system?

Comment: I would first do your upgrade WITHOUT any modules. then add your modules after. This will ensure that modules will not interfere with the upgrade

Answer (score 3):

> During this time, we might get orders in the old Magento installation. How can we get this orders sync with the new system?

You don't.

When you conduct your first upgrade it should be in a disposable, non-production environment. So that you can fully test the store, understand and fix any issues that arise.

When you are ready to upgrade your production store, you should put it into maintenance mode (to prevent new orders), and run your upgrade, observing any notes from your previous tests.

Comment: _When you conduct your first upgrade_ multiple times in a development environment that closely approximates your live server in OS and server configuration until you have worked out all module compatibilities, template issues and database upgrade issues... and then fully test all frontend and third party module integrations; then you will be ready to move it to your staging server you have set up in a subdomain to test it in your live server environment for full environment compatibility before final commit to your live ecommerce server. **Don't be a statistic.**