# How to perform automated regression testing for Magento upgrade

Tags: upgrade, testing

I see several questions related to testing a Magento website including ["How to test Magento upgrade"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44178/how-to-test-magento-upgrade), which discusses manual testing.

Are there any tools for automated regression testing of my upgrade?   An ideal tool would learn my products etc. from the database (or previous crawl) and make sure everything is functioning after the upgrade.

I'm sure nothing will replace manual testing for many of the extensions and for the theme/template.  But a general sanity check of an automated regression test would be valueable.

I might even use the automated regression after installing any new extensions.

Answer (score 6):

### Magento Test Automation Framework

The Magento Test Automation Framework (TAF) is used for precisely this reason.  It leverages PHPUnit and Selenium to perform unit and functional tests.  You can write your own custom tests for it as well.

The only downside is that it is deprecated.  It hasn't been updated since Magento 1.7.  So any new features will not be available for coverage.

Magento was written before testing was the norm inside of PHP, so there are areas where the TAF doesn't have 100% code coverage.

Here is the [Github Repository.](https://github.com/magento/taf)

Here is the [installation guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/download/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkInstallationGuide.pdf).

Here is the [user guide](https://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/download/MagentoTestAutomationFrameworkUsersGuide.pdf).

### Ecomdev_PHPUnit

If you wanted to write some of your own PHPUnit tests, this is one of the best modules for doing so.

Download [here](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit).

### Watir / BlueTir

The ruby web driver that allows for functional testing.  Luis Tineo created a hybrid called "BlueTir" that is Magento specific.

Read about Watir [here](http://watir.com/).

Download Blutir [here](https://github.com/kingletas/bluetir).

Answer (score 1):

There are many testing platforms that you can use with Selenium being on of the more usable versions. There are also a number of 3rd party sites that will help you use Selenium (http://www.seleniumhq.org/) for automated testing.

I have used this:
http://saucelabs.com/

But there are many more available.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools

This is a really broad question and may not be best served on this forum. This can be done on any site and does not have to be a Magento site.

Comment: Yes, understood there are general purpose tools for web app testing.  Just seems that something that knows Magento, such as the database schema for data driven testing, might be more applicable.